# No route found for "GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/entity name/"

Tags: php, sql, symfony, web-development-server

i've done CRUD of every entity in my DB with make:crud  , but when i write http://127.0.0.1:8000/ to control the entity add , remove ... it shows me this message " No route found for "GET [http://127.0.0.1:8000/demandededevis/"](http://127.0.0.1:8000/demandededevis/%22) or this "Case mismatch between loaded and declared class names: "App\Entity\devisgaragiste" vs "App\Entity\DevisGaragiste"."

plus when i try to reach a table that has no relations with other table it shows and i can do all crud options  but when with a related one it shows the messages as i said

Comment: It looks like incorrect capitalization of `devisgaragiste` somewhere. Search in your entire project and correct it. Let me know if it helped.

Answer (score 0):

I think, the first thing you have to do is listing all routes from your project. After that, you should find your problematic route in the list, and you will know what to change in your code.

Since you work in Symfony, you should run this command:

```
php bin/console debug:router
```

You will find that route and see it's path.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: this looks more like a comment